# javascript filesize function glitch with bytes between 1000 and 1024

Tags: javascript, math, filesize

So I created this function, it adapts the amount of bytes to the right binary unit. The problem I am having is that whenever a file is between 1000 and 1024 bytes it shows up as: `1.02e+3 KB`. Am I doing something wrong or did I forgot to catch all exception? Thanks for the help.

```
var ce_sizeSuffixes = [" B", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB"];

function grid_filesizeCellClientTemplate(bytes) {
    if (!bytes)
        return "";

    var e = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024));
    var size = (bytes / Math.pow(1024, Math.floor(e)));
    var unit = ce_sizeSuffixes[e];
    //bug with a size >= 1000 and < 1024
    return '<span title="' + bytes + ' bytes">' + (e === 0 ? size : size.toPrecision(3)) + unit + '</span>';
}
```

Solution:

```
var ce_sizeSuffixes = [" B", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB"];
function grid_filesizeCellClientTemplate(bytes) {
if (!bytes)
    return "";

var e = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024));
var size = (bytes / Math.round(size * 1000) / 1000));
var unit = ce_sizeSuffixes[e];
//bug with a size >= 1000 and < 1024
return '<span title="' + bytes + ' bytes">' + (e === 0 ? size : size.toPrecision(3)) + unit + '</span>';
```

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue. Where are you running this?

Comment: Same as above, and I think you should be using 1000 instead of 1024.  Read this... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix

Comment: That's what `toPrecision` does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toPrecision` outputs the number formatted to the given number of significant digits. `1010`, or any number between `1000` and `1024` in your case, has 4 significant digits but you tell the code to give 3. Hence, `1.01e+3`.

If you want to round the number to 3 decimal places, consider `Math.round(size*1000)/1000` instead.

Comment: Have you been able to replicate the "bug"? If so, how?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Open browser console, type `1010..toPrecision(3)`, get `"1.01e+3"`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol So you mean my return statement should look something like:  return '<span title="' + bytes + ' bytes">' + (e === 0 ? size : Math.round(size*1000)/1000) + unit + '</span>';  since this doesn't change  anything for me

Comment: You could, more succintly, incorporate it into your `var size = ...` code, but that should absolutely work.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks! (Bedankt!)